# Will find() ever act nondeterministically?

Tags: scala, find, non-deterministic

I know if I run a simple `find()` function such as `(1 to 5).find(_ < 6)`, I will always get back `Some(1)`.

Here, `find()` is deterministic and will always return the same result, even though the collection `(1 to 5)` contains four other elements that make the predicate `_ < 6` true.

My question is - can `find()` ever act nondeterministically?

Does there exist a collection and/or a predicate that will make `collection.find(predicate)` return different results for successive executions?

Comment: You could just use a predicate that returns random values? Or do you want to limit yourself to pure predicate functions?

Comment: Use a mutable collection and change it between the `find` executions? For bonus points, do it from different threads.

Comment: Although those suggestions will definitely change `find`'s results, that's not exactly what I was looking for. I was wondering if `collection.find(predicate)` would ever return a different result for some unchanging collection and predicate. For instance, if there was some sort of collection object that find would traverse nondeterministically?

Comment: Depends on how strict your definition of "unchanging" is. One might be able to devise an immutable unsorted map that is mutable "on the inside" and changes traversal order as part of get operations as an optimisation. Though that would just be leaking (unwanted) mutability again.

Comment: Interesting - so it is possible to create an implementation of a Map where the content of the Map would not change, but the traversal order would? Do you know if anyone has created such a thing, or how I could create one myself?

Comment: It's possible to create almost any nonsense :-) Casually changing traversal order might break some contracts though (like the one you seem to ask about), this is not enforced by the compiler anywhere. Whether it's been done, and whether it would be considered buggy, I don't know.

Comment: For what I see, many existing implementations of `find` [uses `Iterator` object](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L77) to [traverse the collection](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L981). When you implement your own collection, you can make any implementation of `find` you want.

Comment: I think all collections in `scala.collections` package are trying to be as deterministic as possible - because it make sense to do it that way. But to know for sure, you would have to manually examine all those implementations of `find` in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a linear sequence, `find` will always proceed linearly, and thus it will always return the same element.

This is not necessarily true for a non-linear collection such as `Set`.

```
Set(1 to 5: _*).find(_ < 6) // Some(5)
Set(1 to 5: _*).find(_ < 6) // Some(5)
```

Here you get a different element, although the implementation seems to be deterministic due to value equality.

This equality can easily be broken:

```
// reference equality
class Box(val peer: Int) { override def toString = peer.toString }

def mkIndet() = Set((1 to 5).map(new Box(_)): _*)

mkIndet.find(_.peer < 6) // "random"
mkIndet.find(_.peer < 6) // "random"
mkIndet.find(_.peer < 6) // "random"
```

---

Another case is parallel collections:

```
def par() = (1 to 10000).par.find(i => i % 1000 == 0)

par()  // "random"
par()  // "random"
par()  // "random"
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your code. I understand that `(1 to 5).map(new Box(_))` transforms the Range into a Vector of Boxes. But why does converting the Vector of Boxes into a Set randomize the order, but converting the Range into a Set does not?

Comment: Maybe it should be written as `(1 to 5).map(new Box(_)).asSet`

Comment: @Shuklaswag because the set organises its backing array based on hash codes. For references types, unless you specifically implement `hashCode` that is the memory location of the object, so in each run you will have random hash codes and thus random sorting order.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea that's how Sets were sorted! Fascinating. Well, your examples definitely qualify as nondeterministic find operations!